# How to create a Mac APP from existing flask application

Tags: python, py2app

I am using py2app to create a self contained Mac app from existing Flask application. This is meant to be an installable backend of a web-app that runs locally in the MAC. The code is organised as follows:

```
 <project folder>

      usd_utility

           __init__.py

           usd_utility.py
```

when I do `py2applet --make-setup usd_utility` from project folder I get the error:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

what is the proper way to build the Mac APP?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac use [platypus](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) If you have included all dependent assests, you will be able to run easily, it also support few other languages although I haven't tried. You wouldn't need a tutorial its pretty straight forward

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I have been trying to use platypus without full success. I am launching the flask app with a .sh script that activates the virtual environment (source .venv_usd/bin/activate) and then calls flask. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to detect the virtual environment and I get the following message: script: line 49: flask: command not found. Interestingly if I launch the .sh script with command line it works well

Comment: did you know you can use some python code to activate some cli stuff, so instead of making a complete standalone instead make a invisible file using a dot before a `.runpython.sh`. to make it invisible unless you run `ls -a` and the hash, and now make a Python Standalone using platypus to trigger the file which opens it. So basically the .sh file is making it run, and a separate standalone is run to open it.
```python
import os
os.system("open .runpython.sh")
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get platypus work. Nice tool. I've just ensured that virtual environment in included in the bundled with no missing installed packages and activated the virtual environment in the script file.